# ASP.Net Web API - JSON sem acentuação %20 %C3%A7

Tags: json, api, aplicação-web, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou consumindo uma api mas o JSON de retorno não vem com a acentuação correta.
no lugar do espeço vem %20, por exemplo.

no json de requisição eu até coloco o encoding.UFT8.

Como posso codificar isso corretamente?

```
private string jsonRequest = @"{'action': {'name': 'get_user_drivers','parameters': [{'driver_id': '','active_drivers': '','group_id': '','version': ''}],'session_token': '" + Helpers.TraffilogLogin.GetAuthToken() + "'}";

var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.Clear();
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpClient httpClientInstance = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClientInstance.PostAsync(BaseApi.traffilogApiUrl, content).Result;

JArray groupListJson = (JArray)JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)["response"]["properties"]["data"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) para decodificar o seu conteúdo.

```
string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url); //decodedUrl é o conteúdo que você precisa decodificar.
```

Essa codificação se chama [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Não entendi. Essa url é a resposta ou a url da api mesmo?

Comment: É a resposta, o nome do método é `UrlDecode` pois geralmente se usa Percent-encoding para URL, a resposta que você recebe esta totalmente codificada ou apenas alguns atributos? por exemplo um campo de url. Edita a pergunta com a resposta codificada de exemplo.

Comment: Mas respondendo, você passaria assim: `string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(RESPOSTA);`

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta com o código que estou usando. Onde eu usaria esse UrlDecode? Não são todos caracteres. Até agora reparei que é o espaço, dois pontos, ç, ~

Comment: insira a resposta que você recebe, tipo o JSON puro sabe?

Comment: Esse HttpUtility é do System.Web? Não acho a referência dele.

Comment: Consegui. Estou usando console app então é outro name space: System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(string)